# Why do AWS resources use names as keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The most recent example is the ECS (Elastic Container Service) where resources like tasks or services are all identified by their name, not a resource-ID (some sort of a GUID). This approach makes it impossible to change the name of a resource afterwards. If you are not familiar with the ECS, try changing a name of a Security Group, as another example.

One would think this to be an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) that they'd try to avoid with the newer services, but it doesn't seem so. Do you see benefits of such "key-is-name" system design?

Comment: I believe they do use GUIDs internally.  However, for the most part these internal IDs are not exposed to us as clients, unless necessary.  That is good design.  Take EC2 for example.  From our perspective they are identified by name (more specifically, by the instance ARN).  However it's possible to log into an EC2 instance and dump the UUID of the instance.  Even with names, there are a lot of "mappings" / levels of indirections that happen behind the scenes.  E.g., AZ names like "us-east-1c" are actually randomized -- my us-east-1c may be physically different than yours.

Comment: That's my point, since internally it's all GUIDs anyway, why not just stick to that and let users change the names. At that point, a name is just a "friendly" alias nothing more.

Comment: Because ARNs are _really_ IDs, not "names", despite the moniker.  The design obviously parallels the idea of URIs and URNs, which canonical forms were intended to be unique and persistent even after a resource is destroyed ([see RFC8141](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8141)). There may be exceptions but in AWS, IDs (**whether internal or external**) are immutable and unique while "names" are changeable and non-unique (usually definable through _tags_).  This a natural. In real life I cannot change my SSN (id) but I can change my name, which may be the same as someone else's name.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of some resources the name forms part of the ARN which is GUID-like. If you want a vanity name for identification purposes you're better off using tags.

Comment: I guess the key word here is "some resources". The lack of consistency is the source of confusion. Instance names can be renamed but not the security groups etc. If the API/console referred to the fields differently like "permanent key" or "resource ID" users would be forewarned about the role of the input they give. I'd outright just put a random UID knowing I cannot alter it and use a Tag to name it whatever I want.